# Ajax Post request not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a form where the user fills information in and clicks submit. Upon clicking, the page will never refresh. Form processing and data handling will happen after the user clicks.

I am trying to use jQuery and Ajax to accomplish this, so far this is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<form class="article_information_form" action="" method="POST"> 
  <label>Title </label> 
  <input type="text" name="articleTitle"> <br> 
  <label>Article URL: </label> 
  <input type="text" name="articleUrl"> <br>
  <p>Number of pages</p>
  <select name="numPages">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <?php echo $message;?> //For Debugging
  <input type="submit" name="article_info_btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST["articleTitle"], $_POST["articleUrl"], $_POST["numPages"])) {
    $message = "Success!"; //For debugging
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).on('submit', '.article_information_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    url  : '', 
    success :  function(data) {
        alert("Success!"); 
    } 
  }) 
})
```

Upon clicking the `submit` button, the success window popup alert is shown. 
Though, the `$message` variable never prints out "success!" This means that its not processing the PHP `$_POST`.

How do I make it so that Ajax sends the information to the PHP `$_POST`?

Comment: It's an AJAX query and they are use to retrieve data in the success function and it will create a new HTTP query. It will not do the query to the same page and affect that page. I think you need to read more about AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".article_information_form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post(window.location , $( this ).serialize() , function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

You didnt attach the data payload!!

Since you wanted the entire thing to be on a single page, this would be a possible way:

Full code for easy understanding:

```
<?php
//exececuted only if POST request as in the ajax below.
if($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST' ){
    //your processing here
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json');
    //lets set the receivedToServer property to what data we got
    $data = array();
    $data['receivedToServer'] = $_POST;
    //output data as json
    echo json_encode($data);
    //kill the page once the data is displayed
    die(); 
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="article_information_form" action="" method="POST">
        <label>Title </label>
        <input type="text" name="articleTitle">
        <br>
        <label>Article URL: </label>
        <input type="text" name="articleUrl">
        <br>
        <p>Number of pages</p>
        <select name="numPages">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="article_info_btn" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $('.article_information_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                //the processed data available as data variable. 
                //lets log the data received at server property we set before
                console.log(data.receivedToServer);
                alert(data.receivedToServer.articleTitle);
            }
        });
    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: alert(result) prints out everything in my document page, but the PHP script is not invoked

Comment: actually it does becuause your php file continues to print.

Comment: $message is not set to "Success!" and is not echo'd out though

Comment: I don't see any difference after adding these lines of code

Comment: @user2896120 my bad!! forgot `echo`. This works, I tested!!

Comment: Alert box seems to be not working now and the echo statement isn't printed for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116292/discussion-between-iceman-and-user2896120).

Comment: Would you like to chat now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data to your ajax call:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.article_information_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        //url: '', by default is the current page url.
        data: $('.article_information_form').serialize(),//This line
        success: function(data) {
            $('.article_information_form type["submit"]').before("<div>"+data+"</div>")
        }
    })
})
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["articleTitle"], $_POST["articleUrl"], $_POST["numPages"])) {
    echo "Success!"; //For debugging
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `url` by default is the current page url ;)

Comment: or you can use `window.location` as well.

Comment: Removing e.preventDefault(); makes it work, but I do not wish to reload the page. How do I use window.location so the page doesn't reload?

Comment: Just remove the url attribute and keep `e.preventDefault();` check the updates

Comment: Hmm I did, but it's still the same

Comment: The variable `$message` will never show up ajax will not compile your PHP !!

Answer (score 0):

You are not pass data to your method so it is not working. So first you will check how many argument have in method, then you send same number of string in params.

You should note one thing about argument are same name as use in method argument name.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.article_information_form', function(e)
             {
                e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({

                      type : 'POST',
                      url  : '',
                      params : {articleTitle: 'Titlename', articleUrl : 'URLName',numPages : 'PagesNo'}
                      success :  function(data)
                      {
                        alert("Success!");
                      }
                  })
             });
```

Comment: The $message is not printed still for some reason

Comment: where is not printed $message

Comment: In my PHP script where $message is set to "Success!"

Answer (score 0):

On your form add an ID, in our case I put an `id="form_submit"` and `action="action.php"`, you need to replace it with your own path where the action should do.

```
<form id="form_submit" class="article_information_form" action="action.php" method="POST">
```

also this line of the form,

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="article_info_btn" value="Submit">
```

change the type `type="bumit"` to `type="button"` to prevent default submission.

and the jquery,

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var submit_url = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    url  : submit_url, 
    data : $('#form_submit').serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    success :  function(data) {
        alert("Success!"); 
    } 
  }) 
})
```

This line `var submit_url = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');` get the path on the `action=""` and use that path to passed data.

Comment: What if the action is the page itself?

Comment: Like for example `localhost/index`, where index is the page itself, put it into action. jquery will get an empty path if you dont have one, and the data may arrive somewhere. Leaving the action empty only if no jquery involve

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, you need to add a `data` parameter to your `$.ajax()` call.

Your other question - reading the comments - is about how you can get the PHP `$message` variable to show up *without* a page load.

That is, unfortunately, impossible without a page-refresh because PHP is rendered on the server side.

What I would suggest, is creating another PHP file that handles the logic that you're trying to create, and then using AJAX to throw the response back onto the current page. Achieving what I believe you want to do.

So! *Example time.*

**first.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>First</title></head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input name="email" type="email" />
      <button>Go!</button>
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <script>
      $('#myForm').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: $().serialize(); // send the form data to..
          url: 'second.php',     // your new PHP page
          complete: function(xhr, status){
            console.log('xhr', xhr);
            console.log('status', status);
            $('#message').text(status);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["email"]) {
    echo "Success!";
  } else {
    echo "Error!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is very understandable, but what is the purpose of the console.log('xhr', xhr)?

Comment: Also, I made two files to mimic your example, but it seems that success is not echo'd out nor is error

Comment: The purpose of the `console.log` is so you can see any output easily. Check your browser's console to see the output. It's not functional - just eases debugging if things do go wrong. You can (and _should_) safely remove it before deploying code to production.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your Ajax Code :-

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(".article_information_form").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "process_page.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                success: function(html) {
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

2- To print AJAX response add the following "div" under the "body" tag :-

```
##<div id='msg' ></div>
```

3- Create a PHP page "process_page.php" to receive the submitted data and then send the result

```
<?php
$numPages = $_POST['numPages'];
echo $numPages; //anything you echo here will be displayed in the <div id='msg'> at the main page
?>
```

good luck